# How to use Arrays.sort() to output names in an alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting, multidimensional-array

I basically want to use Arrays.sort() method to sort the names of the students in aphabetical order and write it onto a new text file called `StudentNames`. I tried doing it but it would give me an error, I do not know if I was suing it correctly or placing in the right position.

Sample input:

```
Select Your Class Size!

A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?
 Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!

6x5

Ok, so you have selected 6x5
Your classroom size looks like this:

XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX

Now Enter The Number Of Students!
4

Enter the names of the 4 students!

Hussain
User
Jacob
Bob

The Student Names Have Been Sorted In An Alphabetical Order
The Names And Seat Location Of The Student Are As Follows:

Hussain Seat Location: (1)(1)
User Seat Location: (1)(2)
Jacob Seat Location: (1)(3)
Bob Seat Location: (1)(4)
```

Sample Output:

```
Select Your Class Size!

A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?
 Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!

6x5

Ok, so you have selected 6x5
Your classroom size looks like this:

XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX

Now Enter The Number Of Students!
4

Enter the names of the 4 students!

Hussain
User
Jacob
Bob

The Student Names Have Been Sorted In An Alphabetical Order
The Names And Seat Location Of The Student Are As Follows:

Bob Seat Location: (1)(1)
Hussain Seat Location: (1)(2)
Jacob Seat Location: (1)(3)
User Seat Location: (1)(4)
```

Output I am Getting:
Select Your Class Size!

```
A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?
 Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!

6x5

Ok, so you have selected 6x5
Your classroom size looks like this:

XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX

Now Enter The Number Of Students!
4

Enter the names of the 4 students!

Hussain

The Student Names Have Been Sorted In An Alphabetical Order
The Names And Seat Location Of The Student Are As Follows:
```

Basically Its not outputting anything, I commented my `catch` print statement so it would show the error I would get, but it outputs nothing.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


// Create a class and method
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Clear the screen
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
    System.out.flush();

    // Create scanner object
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create a print statement
    System.out.println("Select Your Class Size!\n");
    System.out.println("A 6x5 Classroom or a 3X10 classroom?\n Enter '6x5' or '3x10' please!\n");

    String Class1 = "6x5";
    String Class2 = "3x10";

    Double input[] = new Double[1];

    String selectClassSize = inp.next();

    int indexOfx = selectClassSize.indexOf('x');
    int xcount = 0;

    boolean containsx = indexOfx == 0 || indexOfx == (selectClassSize.length() - 2);

    if (containsx) {
      input[xcount] = Double.parseDouble(selectClassSize.replace("x", ""));
      
      System.out.println("\nOk, so you have selected " + Class1);
      System.out.println("Your classroom size looks like this:\n");

      int rows = 6;
      int columns = 5;
      int classSize[][] = new int [rows][columns];
      
      for(int i = 0; i < classSize[0].length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < classSize.length; j++){
            System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
      xcount++;

    } else {
      System.out.println("\nOk, so you have selected " + Class2);
      System.out.println("Your classroom size looks like this:\n");

      int rows2 = 3;
      int columns2 = 10;
      int classSize2[][] = new int [rows2][columns2];
        for(int x = 0; x < classSize2[0].length; x++){
          for(int y = 0; y < classSize2.length; y++){
              System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
    }

    // Create a scanner variable
    System.out.println("\nNow Enter The Number Of Students!");

    int numOfStudents = inp.nextInt();

    // Create a counter variable to count upto the numOfStudents and break the loop
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("\nEnter the names of the " + numOfStudents + " students!\n");
     try {

      // Initialize the new objects
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("StudentNames");
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      String[] names = new String[numOfStudents];
      String[] seats = new String[numOfStudents];
      
      int row = 0, column = 1;
      
      // Output the first names in the 
      for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) {
          names[x] = inp.next();
          if(containsx) {
              if(row >= 6) {
                  column++;
                  row = 0;
              }
          }
          else {
              if(row >= 3) {
                  column++;
                  row = 0;
              }
          }
          Arrays.sort(names); // This is where I put it, but it wouldn't work
          seats[x] = "("+Integer.toString(column)+")" + "("+Integer.toString(++row)+")";
          bw.write(Arrays.toString(names)+" Seat Location: "+seats[x]);
          bw.newLine();
      }

      bw.close();
      fw.close();

      // Catch any errors
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // System.out.println("An Error Occured!");
    }
     try {

      // Initialize the new objects
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("StudentNames");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      String line = br.readLine();

      // Start a while loop to output the data from the file
      System.out.println("\nThe Student Names Have Been Sorted In An Alphabetical Order");
      System.out.println("The Names And Seat Location Of The Student Are As Follows:\n");
      
      while (line != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
          line = br.readLine();
        }
      br.close();
      fr.close();

      // Catch any errors
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      System.out.println("An Error Occured!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message and stack trace to your question.

Comment: You'll need to remove the try/catches so that the errors are reported.

Comment: I commented it but it still wouldnt output anything

Comment: You sort it and assign your seats, all within the same `for` loop that you add the students.  By the time you assing the first student to a seat, you have no idea what other names are going to come up.  You should move the sort and seat assignment to _after_ you have all of the students' names.

Comment: Can you show me if possible

Comment: I could, but it's literally just 'move everything in the `for` loop from `Arrays.sort` onwards  into another `for` loop _after_ the first has finished.

Comment: what other for loop?

Comment: The other one you add in order to address the problem.  You don't have it yet.

Comment: Could you show me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what [BeUndead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478398/beundead) wants to say is:

```
  // Output the first names in the 
  for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) {
      names[x] = inp.next();
  }

  Arrays.sort(names); // This is where I put it, but it wouldn't work

  for (int x = 0; x < numOfStudents; x++) {
      if(containsx) {
          if(row >= 6) {
              column++;
              row = 0;
          }
      }
      else {
          if(row >= 3) {
              column++;
              row = 0;
          }
      }
      seats[x] = "("+Integer.toString(column)+")" + "("+Integer.toString(++row)+")";
      bw.write(Arrays.toString(names)+" Seat Location: "+seats[x]);
      bw.newLine();
  }
```

But, you must understand, it's just a starting point. There are many more errors in your code. Make that change, check the results and ask again more specific questions.

Comment: When i try to rn the code, it wouldn't recognize seats[x]